# From HTTP to HTTPS, the sooner the better?

Tags: https, security

If I have this page in "http://example.com/login" with GET verb:

```
<form action="https://example.com/login" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="login"/>
   <input type="password" name="pass"/>
   <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
</form>
```

Is it a security flaw? I mean, the page is HTTP but when sending the data it uses HTTPS. I have read several times that I should require HTTPS already in the login page, but I don't clearly see why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's flawed.  What you have is secure as far as it goes, *as long as it's your login form the user is seeing*.

Because your login form isn't secured, I can come along and substitute my own spoof login form and collect your users' login details, eg. via a man-in-the-middle attack.  A login system is only secure if both the login form and the target page use SSL.

Also, it doesn't look secure to the user.  Users look for the padlock symbol on the login form, and yours doesn't have one.

Comment: Well, it seems that you have changed your opinion drastically. :)

Comment: @Gumbo: I answered without engaging my brain, then corrected myself.  Normally I try to engage my brain *before* answering, but I'm undercaffeined this morning.  :-)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, **it is a security flaw**.

Since the form is served over HTTP, it is subject to being edited along the way. This edit could be, for example, the additional of JavaScript that sends the credentials to a server that the attacker controls as well as letting the browser log in normally.

Comment: @Quentin, so you are saying that Twitter has a security flaw in its login process? Because it uses exactly the same: twitter.com is served over HTTP and the login form situated on its home page uses HTTPS (except that it uses POST instead of GET but this doesn't really matter)

Comment: Yes, although they do also provide the form over https, so it is possible to avoid the problem if you are careful.

Comment: @Quentin, I am not sure I understand you. The form is present on twitter.com which is served over HTTP. How is this different than the OPs scenario? I am not persuaded with your explanation.

Comment: If you visit `http://twitter.com/` you get the form without SSL and it is subject to the problem described above. If you visit `https://twitter.com/` then you get the form with SSL and it isn't.

Comment: @Quentin, most people will visit `http://twitter.com`. How many of them do you think will use `https://twitter.com` before logging in? Your explanation doesn't hold for me.

Comment: When I said "if you are careful" I meant "as a visitor to twitter.com". This doesn't do the vast majority of visitors any good (since they don't know better), but does allow us to protect ourselves.

Comment: @Quentin, maybe you are right. I am not a specialist in security. What I see is how this is implemented on a very high traffic site. And I think that the people that implemented it have far better understanding on security than me. So I thought they knew what they were doing in order to protect their users. Once again, I cannot argue as I don't have enough understanding in this field.

Comment: @Quentin, after giving a second thought and rereading your answer and comments carefully it makes sense. Because the login form is served over an unencrypted channel there is no way for the user to ensure that its contents haven't been tampered with. The only way to ensure this is to use SSL. +1 for your answer.

Comment: Great explanation, thanks! Sorry I marked the other as answer just for  being 3 mins early :P